# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context with ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables named `Conversation` and `AspNetUsers`.
So, a `Conversation` has more than one `AspNetUsers`. 
When I find the `Conversation` that has the specified `AspNetUsers` users with

```
List<Conversation> conversations = db.Conversations.Where(m => 
                                   (m.AspNetUsers.Contains(currentUser) && 
                                    m.AspNetUsers.Contains(receiverUser))).ToList();
```

I got this error

> Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

`Contains` is just for primitive type, which translates to `IN` in SQL. Use `Any` and provide the condition for checking(Assuming the users have Id):

```
List<Conversation> conversations = db.Conversations
     .Where(m => (m.AspNetUsers.Any(x=> x.Id == currentUser.Id) && 
                  m.AspNetUsers.Any(x=> x.Id == receiverUser.Id))).ToList();
```

Comment: ohhhh, I got it. Thank you so much